# Generate correct name with fields_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, fields-for

```
= f.field_for @user.account || @user.build_account do |account|
  = account.text_field :name
```

Is generating

```
<input name="user[account][name]">
```

and I want:

```
<input name="user[account_attributes][name]">
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed was:

```
= f.fields_for :account, @user.account || @user.build_account do |account|
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing by, I would like to mention the `object_name` method

`account.object_name` should return `"user[account_attributes]"`

So if you concatenate your field name between brackets `"[field_name]"`, you can easily construct the right name for your input's field